# Javascript: possible to dynamically create a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, trie

I'm playing around with multidimensional arrays in Javascript.
Basically I'm trying to put letters of a string into some kind of Trie (actually a Radix Tree), using a multi-dimensional array.

```
  var data= [];
  var word="test";

  if (l=word[0]) {
      if (!data[l]) {
          data[l] = [];
      }
  }
  if (l=word[1]) {
      if (!data[word[0]][l]) {
          data[word[0]][l] = [];
      }
  }
  if (l=word[2]) {
      if (!data[word[0]][word[1]][l]) {
          data[word[0]][word[1]][l] = [];
      }
  }
  if (l=word[3]) {
      if (!data[word[0]][word[1]][word[2]][l]) {
          data[word[0]][word[1]][word[2]][l] = [];
      }
  }

  console.log(data);
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TN28c/

I was wondering if this could be automated (without using `eval()`) to handle any-length words. I know Javascript doesn't have pointers/references, which is what I would probably use in PHP, but is there maybe another way?

I'm not looking for a trie-library, I already found some of these, but I was just wondering if the above is even possible to do dynamically in Javascript.

Comment: **Everything** is dynamic in JavaScript.  Why wouldn't it be possible? Don't you see the `for` loop pattern in the code you posted? (Sorry if that seems harsh; I didn't mean it derisively.)

Comment: One off-topic technical note: PHP doesn't have pointers either.  It has *references*, which are superficially similar, but have some important differences.

Comment: What is your intended output for the string `test`? The malformed array you're generating seems _odd_ to me.

Comment: @Mathletics it's basically a Trie - the top level is an index of the first letters of (a set of) words, the second is the second letters after a particular first letter, etc.

Comment: @Pointy ha, I had to look up [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which makes a lot more sense now. TIL!

Comment: To OP, the [wikipedia page for trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) has an algorithm that looks simple to convert to JS.

Comment: I definetely see the for loop pattern, but I can't think of a way to do it. I tried using some kind of stack to store the current level of data but this seems to create a clone of the array instead of a reference (or pointer)

Comment: @Dylan you need two loops. The outer level would work its way through the word, and then at each level you'd have to get through the array. Probably it'd be a lot easier to do a recursive version.

Comment: Actually, it's some kind of Radix Tree , a special kind of Trie

Comment: why not using data[word[0]][word[1]][word[2]]... with Objects rather than arrays ???

Comment: well, as I said I was just curious if it was possible with arrays too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var word= 'tree';
var data = [];
var obj = data;
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (!obj[word[i]]) {
        obj[word[i]] = []
    }
    obj = obj[word[i]];
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, but I don't understand it. obj is never copied back to data, but data DOES contain the multi-dimensional array in the last line... how is this possible?

Comment: Actually `obj` and `data` are just different references to the same object at the beginning. It doesn't need to be copied back. `obj` is changed through the iterations just to point sub objects of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple recursive version as an example. You could do it iteratively too of course.

```
function trieAdd(trie, word) {
  function addWorker(trie, position) {
    var l = trie[word[position]];
    if (!l)
      trie[word[position]] = l = [];

    if (position < word.length - 1)
      addWorker(l, position + 1);
  }

  addWorker(trie, 0);
  return trie;
}

trieAdd([], "test");
```

Comment: @RainingChain not with a [suitable programing font](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) it isn't.

Comment: @RainingChain ?? why? What's wrong with "l"?  It's a nice letter. "Love" starts with "l"!!  So does "lollipop".  Also "licorice". And "lorakeet".

Comment: @Pointy your response actually does a great job of backing up _my_ response.

Comment: @Mathletics oh thanks - I fixed that in my Firebug console but forgot to in the answer!